# Why doesn't a child's margin affect a parent's height?

Tags: css

In a simple example like this one, the child margin does not affect parent height:

```css
.parent{ background: 
    black; 
}
.child{
    background: LightBlue;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">Some text...</div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k1eegxt3/

By default, child margins do not affect parent height respectively parent dimensions in general, it is easily **fixed by adding something that margin could "push" to** in parent element, e.g. **add a padding or border to parent.:**

```css
.parent{ background: 
    black;
    padding: 1px; /* PADDING ADDED */ 
}
.child{
    background: LightBlue;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fej3qh0z/

I want to know *why* this works this way, not just how it is fixed.

Can someone explain, ideally with a reference to the specification, why this works this way?

Comment: You mean [collapsing margins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing)?

Comment: @j08691 well that is just telling more about when can the problem occur and how to solve it, does not really explain, but thanks :)

Comment: You should read the links at the bottom of that page.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

What you are looking for is called **collapsing margins**. One reason that margins collapse so that empty elements do not add vertical margin space and also to evenly space elements without the need of resetting their margins.

From the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-box-3/#margins):

> ##### 3. Margins
>
> Note: Adjoining margins in block layout can *collapse*. See [CSS2§8.3.1 Collapsing Margins](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins) for details. Also, margins adjoining a [fragmentation break](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-break-4/#fragmentation-break) are sometimes truncated. See [CSS Fragmentation 3 §5.2 Adjoining Margins at Breaks](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-break-3/#break-margins) for details.

The first link in that quote is to this:

> ##### 8.3.1 Collapsing margins
>
> In CSS, the adjoining margins of two or more boxes (which might or might not be siblings) can combine to form a single margin. Margins that combine this way are said to *collapse*, and the resulting combined margin is called a *collapsed margin*.
>
> Adjoining vertical margins collapse, except:
>
> - Margins of the root element's box do not collapse.
> - If the top and bottom margins of an element with [clearance](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#clearance) are adjoining, its margins collapse with the adjoining margins of following siblings but that resulting margin does not collapse with the bottom margin of the parent block.

You can add an `overflow` property to the parent element to fix this (either `auto`, `hidden`, or something else depending on your needs).

JSFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/k1eegxt3/2/

Answer (score 4):

Add `display: flex;` to parent element adjust the flex direction, align, and justify as you want, but the margin thing with appear as you want.

Comment: normally, it is a good idea to add an actual code snippet instead of including code as part of explanations. the answer editor has lot of formatting options for showing code, and separating it from the answer.

Comment: agree, but copying the code and not trying to find out what's behind it won't be the great idea, searching and struggling will have better results

Comment: This does not answer the question or explain how the recommendation might help someone with a related issue.