# Strange behavior of css margins

Tags: html, css, margin

I'm creating a webpage and set margin

```
margin: 120px auto 0 auto;
```

unfortunately the div which is above my div is also changing margin
You can see it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/n5tptwve/1/).

Comment: Which divs are you talking about?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Child margin doesn't affect parent height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27829250/child-margin-doesnt-affect-parent-height)

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here

Comment: It was header and bckr-image. Answer from Syden resolves the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting `absolute` `position` to `.bckr-image`, add `top: 0px;` if you don't want margin.

`.header` is empty pushing `.row` down, is this intended?

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
}
html {
    font-family: "Lucida Sans", sans-serif;
}
.bckr-image
{ 
 margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
 background-image:url(http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg);
  /*linear-gradient(white, #ADD8E6);
 background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;*/
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: top, bottom;
 z-index:-1;
 filter: blur(5px);
 position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

.container
{ 

 background-image: url(http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 width: 80%;
 z-index:0;
 margin: auto;
}


.header {
 margin: 120px auto 0 auto;
    height: 350px;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 100px;
    
}
.menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.menu li {
    padding: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    background-color: #33b5e5;
    color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}
.menu li:hover {
    background-color: #0099cc;
}
.aside {
    background-color: #33b5e5;
    padding: 15px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}
.footer {
    background-color: #0099cc;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 15px;
}
/* For mobile phones: */
[class*="col-"] {
    width: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
 
    /* For tablets: */
    .col-m-1 {width: 8.33%;}
    .col-m-2 {width: 16.66%;}
    .col-m-3 {width: 25%;}
    .col-m-4 {width: 33.33%;}
    .col-m-5 {width: 41.66%;}
    .col-m-6 {width: 50%;}
    .col-m-7 {width: 58.33%;}
    .col-m-8 {width: 66.66%;}
    .col-m-9 {width: 75%;}
    .col-m-10 {width: 83.33%;}
    .col-m-11 {width: 91.66%;}
    .col-m-12 {width: 100%;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    /* For desktop: */
    .col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
    .col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
    .col-3 {width: 25%;}
    .col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
    .col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
    .col-6 {width: 50%;}
    .col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
    .col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
    .col-9 {width: 75%;}
    .col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
    .col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
    .col-12 {width: 100%;}
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="bckr-image"></div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-3 col-m-3 menu">
        <ul>
          <li>My:)</li>
          <li>Zdjęcia</li>
          <li>Prezenty</li>
          <li>Mapa</li>
        <li>Kontakt</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="col-6 col-m-9">
        <h1>The City</h1>
        <p>Chania is the capital of the Chania region on the island of Crete. The city can be divided in two parts, the old town and the modern city.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-3 col-m-12">
        <div class="aside">
          <h2>What?</h2>
          <p>Chania is a city on the island of Crete.</p>
          <h2>Where?</h2>
          <p>Crete is a Greek island in the Mediterranean Sea.</p>
          <h2>How?</h2>
          <p>You can reach Chania airport from all over Europe.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

  </div>

    <div class="footer">
      <p>Resize the browser window to see how the content respond to the resizing.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Temporary solution:
add this css:

```
body{
    padding-top:0.001em; 
}
```